# How to access the key from the tuple in python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have dictionary like this;

```
  csvDict[key] = {'delivery': delivery, 'tanksystemid': tanksystemid}
```

Im trying to do a condition check like;

```
tanksystemid=100

for dic in csvDict.values():
                if tanksystemid == dic['tanksystemid']:
                    key of csvDict?
```

How can i get the key of the csvDict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: If you need the key, use `for key, value in csvDict.items():` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just use `csvDict.items()` instead of `csvDict.values()`. Like (python3) :

```
tanksystemid=100
for key, dic in csvDict.items():
                if tanksystemid == dic['tanksystemid']:
                    # key of csvDict?
                    print(f'key: {key}')
```